# MUL(Assembler) in C

Tags: c, multiplication

In Assembler i can use the MUL command and get a 64 bit Result EAX:EDX,
how can i do the same in C ? http://siyobik.info/index.php?module=x86&id=210

My approach to use a uint64_t and shift the Result don't work^^

Thank you for your help (=

Me

Comment: Please post the C code you used, and the results you were expecting, and we can go from there...

Comment: I'm pretty sure your problem is that you're trying to cast to `uint64_t` *after* multiplying rather than before. Cast one of the arguments up before multiplying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any decent compiler will *just do it* when asked.

For example using VC++ 2010, the following code:

```
unsigned long long result ;
unsigned long a = 0x12345678 ;
unsigned long b = 0x87654321 ;

result = (unsigned long long)a * b ;
```

generates the following assembler:

```
mov         eax,dword ptr [b] 
mov         ecx,dword ptr [a] 
mul         eax,ecx 
mov         dword ptr [result],eax 
mov         dword ptr [a],edx
```

Comment: Why is your assembly destroying `a` after the multiplication? It appears to be storing the higher portion of the result in `a`. Your C source does not do anything like that.

Comment: @AndreyT: It is not my assembly, it is the compiler's!  I wondered about that too, and considered removing it from the post, but that was the code the debugger associated with that line.  Unlike @binary I have learned that it is most often not worth worrying about what the compiler generates, so long as it is correct.

Comment: Well, the problem is that at the first sight the code is obviously not correct, although without more context it is hard to say if this is some weird optimization. I mean, it could be that the compiler decided to overlap the storage occupied by `a` and by `result`, which might be OK is `a` is never used afterwards.

Comment: @AndreyT:  More likely that the line of assembler was associated with whatever followed (which was the return from main()), but the debug information had no specific line to associate it with.  However I don't think it particularly relevant; the point stands that the compiler generated code that used the mul instruction.  Should I just remove the line and pretend that I never saw it!? It seems to have distracted from the main point.

Comment: I am no x86 assembler expert; that's what the compiler is for.  I offer no explanation, and don't care enough to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Post some code. This works for me:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  uint32_t x, y;
  uint64_t z;
  x = 0x10203040;
  y = 0x3000;
  z = (uint64_t)x * y;
  printf("%016" PRIX64 "\n", z);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have it now like uint64_t a = b * c; a = a >> 32; ;)

Comment: You mean this uses the `MUL` instruction? Did you check?

Comment: `grep mul 4099867.s` returns `       imulq  %rdx, %rax`. Apparently my compiler doesn't use `MUL` when assembling that code without optimizimations. With full optimizations, the `grep` returns nothing

Comment: It would only use `mul` if the operands and result were unsigned.

Comment: To avoid strength reduction in your test, better get your operands from command line args.

Comment: With registers named %rdx, you are compiling in 64 bits.

Comment: @pmg: My apologies, I misread the authorship of the comment, and did not notice that it was related to *your* code.  Interestingly when I coded it in VC++ with signed types it generated an imul, and with unsigned a mul - hence my comment.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can get the equivalent of [__emul or __emulu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2s81xt0.aspx) for your compiler(or just use this if you've got an MS compiler). though 64bit multiply should automatically work unless your sitting behind some restriction or other funny problem(like _aulmul)

Comment: Hmm, now the Multiplication just worked, thanks anyway to both of you =)

Answer (score 0):

You mean to multiply two 32 bit quantities to obtain a 64 bit result?

This is not foreseen in C by itself, either you have tow 32 bit in such as `uint32_t` and then the result is of the same width. Or you cast before to `uint64_t` but then you loose the advantage of that special (and fast) multiply.

The only way I see is to use inline assembler extensions. gcc is quite good in this, you may produce quite optimal code. But this isn't portable between different versions of compilers. (Many public domain compilers adopt the gcc, though, I think)

Answer (score 0):

#include

```
/* The name says it all.  Multiply two 32 bit unsigned ints and get
 * one 64 bit unsigned int.
 */
uint64_t mul_U32xU32_u64(uint32_t a, uint32_t x) {
  return a * (uint64_t)b; /* Note about the cast below. */
}
```

This produces:

```
mul_U32xU32_u64:
    movl    8(%esp), %eax
    mull    4(%esp)
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

When compiled with:

```
 gcc -m32 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -S mul.c
```

Which uses the `mul` instruction (called `mull` here for multiply long, which is how the gnu assembler for x86 likes it) in the way that you want.

In this case one of the parameters was pulled directly from the stack rather than placed in a register (the `4(%esp)` thing means 4 bytes above the stack pointer, and the 4 bytes being skipped over are the return address) because the numbers were passed into the function and would have been pushed onto the stack (as per the x86 ABI (application binary interface) ).

If you inlined the function or just did the math in it in your code it would most likely result in using the `mul` instruction in many cases, though optimizing compilers may also replace some multiplications with simpler code if they can tell that it would work (for instance it could turn this into a shift or even a constant if the one or more of the arguments were known).

In the C code at least one of the arguments had to be cast to a 64 bit value so that the compiler would produce a 64 bit result.  Even if the compiler had to use code that produced a 64 bit result when multiplying 32 bit values, it may have not considered the top half of it to be important because according to the rules of C operations usually result in a value with the same type as the value with the largest range out of its components (except you can sometimes argue that is not really exactly what it does).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do exactly that in C, i.e. you cannot multiply two N-bit values and obtain a 2N-bit value as the result. Semantics of C multiplication is different from that of your machine multiplication. In C the multiplication operator is always applied to values of the same type `T` (so called *usual arithmetic conversions* take care of that) and produces the result of the same type `T`.

If you run into overflow on multiplication, you have to use a bigger type for the operands. If there's no bigger type, you are out of luck (i.e. you have no other choice but to use library-level implementation of large multiplication).

For example, if the largest integer type of your platform is a 64-bit type, then at assembly level on your machine you have access to `mul` operation producing the correct 128-bit result. At the language level you have no access to such multiplication.

Comment: Despite the troll downvote, the answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: I guess that because while correct, no mention of the simple solution of casting an operand was made.  Very bold to assert your own correctness however ;) +1 to redress the unfairness.

Comment: @Clifford: Well, in order to come up the solution one first needs to understand the problem. Since there's no description of a specific situation in the question, I interpreted the OP's problem literally, as a question about "widening" multiplication in C (`Nbit * Nbit -> 2Nbit`). And, as I said in my answer, unfortunately there's no such multiplication in C. There's no solution. In C multiplication is always `Nbit * Nbit -> Nbit`.

Comment: So, when you need the 2N-bit result, the "solution" would be to switch to `2Nbit * 2Nbit -> 2Nbit` multiplication (if possible), which is what you suggested. But that's not what was requested, according to my interpretation of the question. There's an example in my answer that illustrates the difference: in C you have no access to machine `64-bit * 64-bit -> 128-bit` multiplication if the largest integer type is 64-bit. Machine can do it. C cannot do it. More precisely, C provides no way for you task the machine to do it. That's my point.

Comment: Well you can answer the question that was asked, or the question that should have been asked ;)